# Unexpected behaviour of jQuery val() in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I'm trying to debug one thing I've encountered today, that's as far as I know only happening on Safari:

I've got a standard select element with option elements, each with value attribute. On select change, I fire on-change event and use `$(e.target).val()` to get the selected option value attribute. Now this works great on every browsers BUT Safari.

For example I've got element with `value="13"` and when it's selected, the `$(e.target).val()` returns 23 in Safari, correct in Chrome or Firefox amongst others.

Found a workaround for this by calling e.target.value which returns proper attribute. Still, I'm wondering what might have been causing this behaviour.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `$(this).val()` in the handler?

Comment: Irrelevant. End result is the same. It's not as much of an issue of what to call val() on, but what gets returned

Comment: Unable to replicate in Safari on Windows:  https://jsfiddle.net/txmLhfaq/  Does this happen in iOS only?

Comment: Can't reproduce in Safari on OS X Snow Leopard or Yosemite, either.

Comment: Well I've never had any problem getting the value of a select element via jQuery `.val()` on Safari or any other browser. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: If this were really a problem, there would be thousands of web sites that don't work in Safari.

Comment: And it actually *might* make a difference, depending on what Safari considers the event target to be.

Answer (score 0):

Cause for the behaviour has been found, just in case anyone else is having the same issues.

Since Safari doesn't accept calling `display: none;` on option elements I've used small jQuery plugin: https://gist.github.com/tomdracz/b165d9734aa25ba5aebf

This wraps the options in `<span>` tags with `display: none;` and hides the elements. this however causes `.val()` to return value of the first select option, even wrapped in span and not the selected one. Funnily enough, adding `:selected` selector, returns the correct one. Rails app I'm using is unfortunately just calling `val()` in the ujs, as far as I know and that breaks the params passed from the form.

The solution was to save the options list in a variable and on change detach unused options from the DOM. Then on a next change, I'm attaching the options again to have all of them available for filtering.